# Rails App Not using Precompiled Assets on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails App that loads all the assets on development just fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/text.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/theme-default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/login.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/notify.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" />
```

Whereas on the Production Server, it is still using the above code to load CSS. Shouldn't it be using the /assets/applicaiton.css file instead? I have run the rake assets:precompile task manually on production and I can see it has created the required files in the /public/assets folder.

So, what do I need to do to tell Rails to use the compressed files?

My production.rb looks like this :-

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

 # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
 config.assets.compress = true

 # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
 config.assets.compile = false

 # Generate digests for assets URLs
 config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the stylesheet_link_tag helper to call the css file like this :

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
```

and insert your stylesheets inside the application stylesheet file like :

```
= require reset
= require text
= require button
...
```

Modify then your production.rb file to set the config.assets.compile as true

```
 # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
 config.serve_static_assets = true

 # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
 config.assets.compress = true

 # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
 config.assets.compile = true

 # Generate digests for assets URLs
 config.assets.digest = true
```

"Should work"

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. What would I need to do if I DID NOT want the Production Mode to compress the files at all? So they would be served just like they are in development mode? It's a backend app and only a few people will use, so really don't want to be bothered with all this complication.